# Angular 2 with webpack (Cannot read property 'exclude' of undefined)

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am following a course from angularclass.com. Following the instruction when I try to run my project I get following error. Can someone help me understand what this error indicate and how to solve it?

[image]

Webconfig file :

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
  cache: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    polyfills: './src/polyfills',
    vendor:    './src/vendor',
    main:      './src/main'
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/,   loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
      { test: /\.html/,  loader: 'raw-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/,  loader: 'to-string-loader!css-loader' },
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: ['polyfills', 'vendor', 'main'].reverse(), minChunks: Infinity }),
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json']
  },

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000 }
  },

  node: {
    global: true,
    process: true,
    Buffer: false,
    crypto: 'empty',
    module: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false,
    clearTimeout: true,
    setTimeout: true
  }
};
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: mind showing your webpack config?

Comment: @harshes53 I have updated it in question

Comment: you might wanna check this [issue](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/190)

Comment: @harshes53 I have seen this thread, non of the solution in it works form me. Dose that mean there is no solution for this?

Comment: there's always a solution! btw, what versions of `typescript` and `awesome-typescript-loader`??

Comment: @harshes53 fixed it I didn't had awesome-typescript-loader. Do you mind adding what dose this do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134840/discussion-between-harshes53-and-ahmad-abdullah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install awesome-typescript-loader explicitly after npm install.